# Angular 7 pipe(tap()) doesn't work the second time

Tags: angular

I have this method getData() that returns an Observable:

```
protected getData(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this._service
                    .getAllData()
                    .pipe(
                        tap(data => {
                            this.items = data.Items;                            
                        })
                    );
            }
```

The first time this function is called, it works fine. The second time, I have no explicit error and "data" inside tap is undefined. The data I get with these methods are mock data, they are all the same and they are static, there's no http request that can go wrong:

```
getAllData(){
    return of( 
        {"Items":
            [{item1},{item2}, ecc]
         })
}
```

Using developer tools I found a generic error on "data" that says "Syntax error, unespected end of input".

What does this mean? Thank you If you want to help me :)

Comment: could you post the `getAllData()` function?

Comment: Where are you subscribing?

Comment: I add the getAllData() method.
The class containing getData() extends another class (call it MyClassBase) and implements getData(). MyClassBase takes the getData() and makes the subscription. 
I have other classes that extend MyClassBase, but this is the first time I need to use getData() more then once

Comment: You need subscribe to an Observable to run it

Comment: So the first time it doesn't need subscription to give me the observable, but the second one it needs it... why?

Comment: could you also post the caller of that function? are you sure you are not subscribing somehow? eg. with `async` pipe or when you using that observable to resolve some router data

Comment: This is how MyClassBase use it:

 ` loadData = _.throttle(() => {
  this.getData()
   .pipe(timeout(2000))
   .subscribe(
    () => this.refresh(),
    err => this.loadingError.emit(err),
    () => {
     this.initialized = true;
    }
   );
 }, 4000);
 `